# UISeachDisplayController showing white box under UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When I click the UISearchBar a white box appears underneath it, but on subsequent calls to the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods the white box disappears. It only displays itself when the user first clicks the UISearchBar. Here is the code in which I initialize the `UISearchDisplayController` and the `UISearchBar`. How can I remove this white box?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    _isSearching = NO;
    self.searchCntrl = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchCntrl.delegate = self;
    self.searchCntrl.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchCntrl.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchCntrl.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;


}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to set the frame of search tableview explicitly.